# How do i get flutter to display the content of a text file

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get the names and the context of some text file to display to screen, so when the file name is clicked it opens a page displaying the full context of the selected file

I've google this for months now but found no help

Comment: For... months?! There's Flutter docs on reading and writing files, writing platform-specific code, displaying content is pretty easy, and there are multiple packages for picking and opening files. What *specifically* can you not figure out?

Answer (score 1):

This doc looks pretty straight forward:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files#2-create-a-reference-to-the-file-location

**TLDR;**

1. Find the path of the file.
2. Initialize File with that path.
3. Read the file as a string.
4. Parse that string as per your need.